# Как высвечивать имя нажатой кнопки в TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

У меня есть три кнопки A, B, C. обработчик одинаков, методом `onClik10()`. У кнопок разные имена. Эти кнопки открывает `NavigationDrawer`. в `NavigationDrawer` есть `TextView`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки высвечивал имя нажатой кнопки в этот `TextView`?

Вот мой код:

```
public void onClick10 (View view){

    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    else{
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    tv.setText (дальше как писать)......???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В метод `onClick(...)` передается `view`, по которому был совершен клик. Соответственно можно у этого `view` брать `id` и далее крутиться от него.

Пример:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First button"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second button"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mFirstButton;
    private Button mSecondButton;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button);
        mSecondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_button);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.first_button:
                mTextView.setText(mFirstButton.getText());
                break;
            case R.id.second_button:
                mTextView.setText(mSecondButton.getText());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```